# Tool to collaborate on text creation and moving around of text blocks

Tags: collaboration, writing, microsoft-office, screenwriting

tl:dr: Looking for a tool in which text blocks can easily be moved along an axis/timeline automatically re-aligning on every change.

**Hello community**

Working together with someone else on a story/script, we have to move around text blocks a lot. 
I'm desperately searching for a tool that can facilitate our quest.

It does not have to be a tool specific for the purpose, much more important are the actual capabilities:

- Text blocks (some small, some much less so, each with a headline) can easily be moved along an axis 
  (think e.g. of a timeline). 
  As soon as a text block is moved, the others around it re-align. When "squeezing" a block between others, they make room. 
  think for example of MIRO stickies, but without restriction on text quantity and the ability to move out of the way if another sticky is positioned between them.
- (annotation) text blocks can be linked to said blocks on the timeline and stay positioned relative to them, i.e. a "timeline block" and its "annotation blocks" move together (like e.g. grouped objects in PPT)
- Absolutely vital is a robust, reliable real-time collaboration ("multiplayer" as I like to call it), where we immediately see the change the other person has made
- Endless scrolling, at least along the main axis, without sheets/pages/slides limiting the available space

I can hardly believe there not being such a tool - yet I haven't found any.

*Tools used / tested until now:*

| Tool | collaboration ("Multiplayer") | Working with text blocks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MS Office (online) | excellent | cumbersome, not automatically re-aligning; constrained to pages/slides unless using VISIO, which requires higher license |
| MIRO | absolutely overwhelmingly excellent | cumbersome; nothing moves out of the way or re-aligns when moving a sticky or shape |
| FinalDraft | VERY immature annoying the hell out of me | semi-OK. So-called "Beats" can be aligned along a timeline, but stay in place on the main board |
| yEd / Graphity | somewhat cluncy via Confluence plugin | Automatically aligns elements as the only tool in this list; but it's difficult with larger text and annoying to handle headers. The tool is made for graphs with only small labels... |

happy to have a look at and try any suggestion!

**Thank you!**

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I did once search for and find authoring/scriptwriting tools. Maybe a search along those lines?

Comment: hmm, we did try celtx - I didn't include it in the tabel, as it only has "script modes" and no "text boxes mode", at least in the free version, and the collaboration was somewhat unstable. But I'll definitely have a look for more authoring tools, thanks @MawgsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: Further search was not very successful either. The best I found was yEd and its Confluence plugin Graphity I now added to the table. At least it can align shapes to a flow automatically  but that's also not it really, as it's not made to handle larger text blocks.